# What do git manual sections mean?

Tags: git

The [git manual](http://git-scm.com/docs) uses page titles like "git-commit(1)" or "git-add(1)" when the commands being discussed are "git commit" or "git add".

What does the "(1)" mean in all these titles??

Comment: This isn't specific to get; UNIX man pages in general use the same scheme. If you're on a UNIX-like system (including Linux), type `man man` for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix man pages (things you access with the `man` command) are nominally separated into various sections.  You can run `man man` to see the standard list of sections, which look something like:

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

All the `git` commands fall into section 1 ("executable programs or shell commands"), and the traditional way for representing this is with the section number in parentheses after the name.  So if someone says, see `ls(1)`, that means "look at the section 1 man page for `ls`".

There are occasionally commands in different sections with the same name.  In this case, you can make the man section explicit. Compare:

```
man reboot
```

With:

```
man 2 reboot
```

Comment: Thanks larsks, I had seen a (7) elsewhere in the git manual, so suddenly this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unix manual pages are divided in sections, so that names could be distinguished. For example, there is a shell command called `printf` and a C function with the same name.

If you look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_page_%28Unix%29#Manual_sections), you will see the following section numbers for Linux:

```
1   General commands
2   System calls
3   Library functions, covering in particular the C standard library
4   Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5   File formats and conventions
6   Games and screensavers
7   Miscellanea
8   System administration commands and daemons
```

So for example [`ls`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) would go in section 1, while [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) would go in section 2 and [`fopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) would go in section 3. Usually they would be written therefore as `ls(1)`, `open(2)` and `fopen(3)` to be clear.

Comment: Thanks Shahbaz - could equally have been accepted answer but could only tick one.

Comment: Sure. I actually up-voted the other answer for mentioning `man N symbol`.